# El valor de una variable se pierde

Tags: bash

Tengo un problema con una variable que quiero mantener, pero supongo que por la referencia de memoria que hace Bash, me la machaca de todas formas.

Tengo una función que llamo con 3 parametros:

```
MiFuncion "Correo sin leer" "pepe@pepe.com" "Este es el Asunto"
```

(este último parametro puede ser una cadena codificada, como esta: "=?utf-8?B?dfICfer43p42rf324orF?=")

```
function MiFuncion() {
 ASUNTO="$3"
 echo "$3" | grep -q '\=\?utf-8\?B'
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   vSubject2=`grep -oP '(?<=B\?).*?(?=\?)' <<< "$3"`
   ASUNTO=`echo "$vSubject2" | base64 --decode`
 fi
echo $2
echo $ASUNTO
}
```

Pero $ASUNTO sale vacio cuando este no viene codificado, es decir, que no se cumple el IF.
Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Nada, fallo mio.
El problema es el IF y la condición que habia puesto, que tenía que chequear que era igual a 0 y no distinto.